# How to put grid in a container element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently doing the front end developer nano degree on Udacity and recently submitted a project practicing using bootstrap. However, I do not quite understand the feedback I got below:

[image]

Is this asking me to have  to wrap around the entire webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the rules when using [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

- Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
- Predefined grid classes like `.row` and `.col-xs-4` are available for quickly making grid layouts. Less mixins can also be used for more semantic layouts.
- Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.
- The negative margin is why the examples below are outdented. It's so that content within grid columns is lined up with non-grid content.
- Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-xs-4`.
- If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.
- Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-*` class is not present.

Comment: As a proud non-bootstraper: tl:dr

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just put `<div class="container">` immediatelly after opening the body tag and close it right before the body ends with `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `.container` or `.container-fluid` div in the body, like the following

```
<body>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
              grid columns
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
```